# AngularJS http.get returns incomplete html-data

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I try to scrape some html-code with AngularJS (with ionic-framkework, to be exact) but the responded html-data seems to be too large.

Calling the url works fine:

```
.factory('$library', ['$http', function($http){

return {

    getBooks: function(){
        var url = 'http://myurl';

        var parseBooks = function(response){                
            var tmp = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument();
            tmp.body.innerHTML = response.data;

            // parsing-code here

            return books;
        }

        return $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
           return parseBooks(response); 
        });
    }}}])
```

The problem is, that response.data seems to be incomplete. Some html-elements I want to access via getElementById are not part of response.data but can be found on the website.
I tried to follow what happens by logging the data and think, that the html-file received is too large.

How can I parse the whole html-content using Angular?

Comment: How does the `response.data` look like exactly? Is it really incomplete (like no `</html>` tag) or is it just that you don't see the elements you think should be there?

Comment: A look into the response headers told me, that the response is chunked, but I don't know how to work with this either

Comment: insted of using **then(function(response) {** try using **success(function(response){**

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks :)